# TypeError: element.getRootNode is not a function while testing

Tags: javascript, react-testing-library, jest-dom

I am using react-testing-library with jest-dom. It is working fine but when i try to use `toBeInTheDocument` it throws the error `TypeError: element.getRootNode is not a function`.

```js
expect(getByText('Not in dom')).not.toBeInTheDocument(); // It works
expect(getByText('Value in DOM')).toBeInTheDocument();  // It throws the error
```

Error log:

```
TypeError: element.getRootNode is not a function
      
      at Object.it (src/x/y/z.test.js:42:34)
          at new Promise (<anonymous>)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: Do you have `jest.config.js` in your project? if you have share this file too.

Comment: No I dont have this file I am using default create-react-app config.

Comment: Could you share all the test code?

Comment: I am running into the same issue. Any tricks on how to circumvent that?

Comment: I was not able to solve this issue but it seems it was due to a lower version of jest/RTL in my project. Because it seems to work in my other project where the deps are updated.

Comment: Had the same issue, @testing-library/jest-dom version 5.x.x was causing the problem, using 4.x.x without any errors atm.